# Constant expression required error setting optional parameter in function

Tags: c#, vb.net

Why am I getting a

> Constant Expression Required

error with the following VB.net code?

```
Public Shared Async Function DownloadAndCountBytesAsync(url As String, Optional token As CancellationToken = New CancellationToken) As Task(Of Integer)
```

Swapping `New CancelationToken` with `Nothing` and adding

```
If token = Nothing Then token = New CancellationToken
```

to the function works but I don't understand why the first option doesn't work...

The same thing seems to work fine in C#

```
public static async Task<int> DownloadAndCountBytesAsync(string url, CancellationToken token = new CancellationToken())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default value for an optional parameter in VB must be known at compile time, which means that it must be a literal, declared constant or `Nothing`.  That means that any reference type other than `String` can only have a default value of `Nothing`.

The way to achieve what you want is by overloading the method:

```
Public Shared Async Function DownloadAndCountBytesAsync(url As String) As Task(Of Integer)
    Return DownloadAndCountBytesAsync(url, New CancellationToken)
End Function

Public Shared Async Function DownloadAndCountBytesAsync(url As String, token As CancellationToken) As Task(Of Integer)
    '...'
End Function
```

Answer (score 2):

C# and VB.Net are different languages, and this is just one difference between them.

In C#, [optional arguments](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx) may be:

> - a constant expression;
> - an expression of the form new ValType(), where ValType is a value type, such as an enum or a struct;
> - an expression of the form default(ValType), where ValType is a value type.

But [in VB.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f25e2b6b.aspx),

> - "The default value for an optional parameter must be a constant expression.

Comment: Note that in the form `new ValType()` it is – frustratingly – required that the constructor have no arguments: it is not enough that it be possible to determine the result of the constructor at compile time for the expression to be considered a “compile-time constant”.